# echoing <div class> not working when using PHP die();

Tags: php, css, echo, die

So I have a form that has some custom made alerts created combined in CSS and PHP, now I call these alerts using echo and I use die() at the end to kill/end the PHP script. Here is the PHP code:

```
if($pass1 != $pass2){
echo '<div class="alert">Passwords do not match!</div>';
die();
}
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.alert {
        background: #fff6bf url(../images/exclamation.png) center no-repeat;
        background-position: 15px 50%; 
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
        border-top: 2px solid #ffd324;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ffd324;
        }
```

The problem is when the script is executed without die() then is shows the error properly with the CSS. When die() is implemented then the code shows a blank page that says "Passwords do not match!" without any styling.

What can I do to kill the PHP script but still have styling?

SOLUTION:

So after seeing the answers and realizing that die kills the entire site at that point. I added a simple line to my code:

BEFORE:

```
   if($pass1 != $pass2){
    echo '<div class="alert">Passwords do not match!</div>';
    die();
    }
```

AFTER:

```
   if($pass1 != $pass2){
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/structure.css">';
    echo '<div class="alert">Passwords do not match!</div>';
    die();
    }
```

So basically I appended just the stylesheet before the alert to make the alert have styling.

Comment: When you use die(); it causes the page to stop rendering at what ever point you were at. So if your HTML isn't finished and you "die" then it cannot be rendered. Example, if your css isn't on the page before your die, then the css cannot be displayed.  You can check this by viewing the source

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `die()` or just dropping out of a script in production. This sounds like more of a program design issue.

Comment: Store the error message to a variable. Later, if the variable is non-empty (there was an error), display it instead of doing whatever else would happen in a non-error state. Don't just suddenly `die()`, halting your script.

Comment: In order for this to work, you would need to have your HTML on top of PHP. I tested this with both `exit('<div class="alert">Passwords do not match!</div>');` and `die('<div class="alert">Passwords do not match!</div>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work with the method you're presently using, you would need to have your HTML on top of PHP.

I tested this with both `exit('<div class="alert">Passwords do not match!</div>');` and `die('<div class="alert">Passwords do not match!</div>');`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>

.alert {
        background: #fff6bf url(../images/exclamation.png) center no-repeat;
        background-position: 15px 50%; 
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
        border-top: 2px solid #ffd324;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ffd324;
        }

</style>
</head>

<?php
$pass1="2"; // my own test variable
$pass2="3"; // my own test variable
if($pass1 != $pass2){

exit('<div class="alert">Passwords do not match!</div>');
// die('<div class="alert">Passwords do not match!</div>');

echo "Hello there"; // Will not echo

}
?>
```

You could do it this way, using an additional conditional statement, instead of killing the script:

```
<?php
$pass1="2"; // my own test variable
$pass2="3"; // my own test variable

$var = "<div class=\"alert\">Passwords do not match!</div>";

if($pass1 != $pass2){
echo $var;
}

else{
echo "You have access.";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<style>

.alert {
font-family:Georgia;
color:#ffff00;

        background: #fff6bf url(../images/exclamation.png) center no-repeat;
        background-position: 15px 50%; 
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
        border-top: 2px solid #ffd324;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ffd324;
        }

</style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likly your css file is added later in the code. When executing a die(); statement php will stop all further processing. Effektivly not echoing the stylesheet.

If you look in your the source of the "blank page" you'll see that it contains:

```
 '<div class="alert">Passwords do not match!</div>'
```